# Quadratic inequality with a parameter

Tags: inequality, quadratics, parametric

I am trying to solve a quadratic inequality with a parameter. I feel dumb as I don't know how to proceed. The inequality is as follows:

$(a + c_1)^2 \le c_2$, where $c_1$, $c_2$ are constants and $c_2$ is negative and $a$ is a parameter of choice. Is there an analytical solution?

Comment: `c_2 is negative` Then there are no solutions, since $(a+c_1)^2 \ge 0\,$ for all real $a, c_1\,$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I can give you the Mathematica output. If you allow `a` to be complex and `c2<0`:

```
Reduce[(a + c1)^2 <= c2 && c2 < 0, a, Complexes]

c2 < 0 && Re[a] == -Re[c1] && 
(Im[a] <= -Im[c1] - Sqrt[-c2 + Re[a]^2 + 2 Re[a] Re[c1] + Re[c1]^2] || 
 Im[a] >= -Im[c1] + Sqrt[-c2 + Re[a]^2 + 2 Re[a] Re[c1] + Re[c1]^2])
```

You get that the real part of `a` and `c1` have to cancel and some conditions on the imaginary parts of `a` and `c1`.